# Code of conduct: "The key has already been imported."

Tags: ppa, openpgp

I would like to activate a PPA, and for that I need to sign the code of conduct. I uploaded my GPG key fingerprint and downloaded the conduct `txt`. But when I access the [signing page](https://launchpad.net/codeofconduct/2.0/+sign) I get this message:

> To sign the Code of Conduct, you must first register your openPGP
>   keys.

I then tried to upload the fingerprint again, but there I get this message:

> The key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX has already been
>   imported.

How do I break from this cycle?

Comment: This seems more like a bug, and I'd got for contacting the Launchpad support directly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sign the Code of Conduct using the [**Code of Conduct Signing Assistant**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/code-of-conduct-signing-assistant.1.html).

[image]

This handy little programme is available from the Ubuntu Software Centre.